# When is Ruby variable declaration+code (on rails) outside function within controller ran?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, constants

Context: was making a simple link shortener (bit.ly style), using base-64 radix conversion, and the alphabet of symbols I used was the constant below: "abc...ABC...012...89", shuffled.

My question: when is this shuffle and join, which is outside functions, ran?

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

    # A declared constant outside of any functions which is shuffled and joined
    SYMBOLS =
  (('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + (0..9).to_a).shuffle.join

end
```

Comment: It is evaluated the first time the class definition is compiled and executed.

Comment: And when does that happen exactly?
My concern was this: if I host this online as a link redirection service, do I risk the SYMBOLS variable changing hence invalidating all the links?

Comment: No, it will only ever be evaluated once the first time the controller is used (because of Rails' autoloading). The example you gave is idempotent anyway. It sounds like you may have a different question though- is that actually what you have in your controller?

Comment: The concern/problem came up because I was testing out the link shortening/unshortening (bit.ly style), and it worked perfectly. A few minutes after, I checked old link redirections (which's values stay the same), and noticed the links began to become invalid. So I assumed SYMBOLS was getting re-evaluated somehow, because the encoding/decoding is depending on it and the only way I can see the links become invalid.

Comment: If a constant changes, you should see a warning in your logs somewhere. It's pretty unlikely it would change unless you're accidentally mutating it in one of your methods.

Comment: Must be that everytime I modify the controller it gets reloaded and so reevaluated, then?

Comment: Every time you boot the app, it will reevaluate your controller. Rails does this for you automatically in development mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple to test yourself:

```
puts "A"
class Test
  puts "B"
  SYMBOLS = 3
  puts "C"
end
puts "D"
```

You'll see this prints A,B,C,D in order, as you'd expect.

Code inside a class declaration is evaluated line by line, just like code anywhere else.

The problem here is that your links somehow depend on the order of a random array. The array will be shuffled randomly each time your program executes, if links require that array to be identical, they're all going to break every time you restart your process.

Comment: Yeah that's precisely it. Thanks!